# image from grayscale to normal went i active or hover the div

Tags: jquery, hover, grayscale

I have an AJAX box with tabify. I am having problems making images change from grayscale to normal when I activate or hover over any of my images. There are 4 images in a row; if one is clicked it changes to normal color, and should stay like that until another is clicked, when the first should revert to grayscale. How can this be done?

The plugin can be found [here](http://unwrongest.com/projects/tabify/); a sample image showing what I want to do is below.

HTML

```
<div id="key-wrap">

<h1>Key Team Members</h1>

<ul id="keyMember" class="keyMember">
<li class="active"><a href="#keyMember1"><div class="keyMember1"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#keyMember2"><div class="keyMember2"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#keyMember3"><div class="keyMember3"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#keyMember4"><div class="keyMember4"></div></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="keyMember1" class="content">
<h2>Limerick One</h2>
<p> The limerick packs laughs anatomical<br />
In space that is quite economical,<br />
But the good ones I've seen<br />
So seldom are clean,<br />
And the clean ones so seldom are comical. </p>
</div>

<div id="keyMember2" class="content">
<h2>Limerick Two</h2>
<p> Let my viciousness be emptied,<br />
Desire and lust banished,<br />
Charity and patience,<br />
Humility and obedience,<br />
And all the virtues increased. </p>
</div>

<div id="keyMember3" class="content">
<h2>Limerick Three</h2>
Hickere, Dickere Dock,<br />
A Mouse ran up the Clock,<br />
The Clock Struck One,<br />
The Mouse fell down,<br />
And Hickere Dickere Dock. 
</div>

<div id="keyMember4" class="content">
<h2>Limerick Three</h2>
Hickere, Dickere Dock,<br />
A Mouse ran up the Clock,<br />
The Clock Struck One,<br />
The Mouse fell down,<br />
And Hickere Dickere Dock.   
</div>

</div> <!--End Key Wrapper-->

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="jquery.tabify.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#keyMember').tabify();
        });

        // ]]>
    </script>
```

CSS

```
body {
font: 0.8em Arial, sans-serif;
}
#key-wrap {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: whitesmoke;
height: 500px;
padding: 10px;
}
.keyMember {
padding: 0;
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
}
.keyMember li {
display: block;
}
.keyMember li a {
background: #ccf;
padding: 10px;
float: left;
border-bottom: none;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
width: 228px;
height: 204px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 200px;
}
.keyMember li.active a {
background: #eef;
}
.keyMember1 {
background:url(members/fulanu.jpg) no-repeat center;
width: 228px;
height: 204px;
}
.keyMember2 {
background:url(members/fulanu.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
.keyMember3 {
background:url(members/fulanu.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
.keyMember4 {
background:url(members/fulanu.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
.content {
float: left;
clear: both;
border-top: none;
border-left: none;
background: #eef;
padding: 10px;
width: 980px;
margin: 30px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML and CSS alone might not cut it for this. Since you're already including jQuery, you might want to take a look at jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass` methods ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/)).

You can bind a handler to each image such that when clicked, CSS classes will be added or removed as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!! it was all CSS, this is what i did...

```
.keyMember1 { background:#CCC; width: 226px; height: 204px; display:inline-block;                                                                                                                                                   position:relative;}
a:hover .keyMember1 { background:#699;}
li.active .keyMember1 {background:gold; }

.keyMember2 { background:#CCC; width: 226px; height: 204px; display:inline-block;    position:relative;}
a:hover .keyMember2 { background:#699;}
li.active .keyMember2 {background:green; }

.keyMember3 { background:#CCC; width: 226px; height: 204px; display:inline-block; position:relative;}
a:hover .keyMember3 { background:#699;}
li.active .keyMember3 {background:blue; }

.keyMember4 { background:#CCC; width: 226px; height: 204px; display:inline-block; position:relative;}
a:hover .keyMember4 { background:#699;}
li.active .keyMember4 {background:red; }
```